# Need advice regarding function assignment

Tags: python

**Thank you for all of the help in calculating the average letter grade that corresponds to average of scores. I also need to list each grade and the corresponding letter grade. I am a little confused on how to do this. Do I make another function to print this?

```
def main():
    student_name = input('Please enter your first and last name: ')
    scores = askForScore()
    avg_score = calc_average(scores)
    letter_grade = determine_grade(avg_score)
    print(student_name)
    print('The average of 8 tests is', letter_grade)
    print('letter_grade\tnumber_grade')
    print('--------------------------')




def askForScore():
    score1 = float(input('Please enter the first test score:'))
    score2 = float(input('Please enter the second test score:'))
    score3 = float(input('Please enter the third test score:'))
    score4 = float(input('Please enter the fourth test score:'))
    score5 = float(input('Please enter the fifth test score:'))
    score6 = float(input('Please enter the sixth test score:'))
    score7 = float(input('Please enter the seventh test score:'))
    score8 = float(input('Please enter the eigth test score:'))
    return (score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8)



def calc_average(scores):
    avg_score = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2] + scores[3] + scores[4] + scores[5] + scores[6] + scores[7]) / 8
    return avg_score



def determine_grade(avg_score):
   if avg_score >= 90 and avg_score <= 100:
       return 'A'
   elif avg_score >= 80 and avg_score <= 89:
       return 'B'
   elif avg_score >= 70 and avg_score <= 79:
       return 'C'
   elif avg_score >= 60 and avg_score <= 69:
       return 'D'
   else:
       return 'F'





main()
```

Comment: Hi @Temple90, could you tell us what you mean by it does not run? Do you get any error? Does it output something at all?

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried?

Comment: Part of the program works. I am able to input a name and input test scores. After that I receive an error message regarding calc_average

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. There were a few problems.

1) When you return a value from a function, you need to assign it to a variable so you can pass it into the next function.

2) String literals like the letter grade "F" need to be inside single or double quote marks.

```
def main():
    student_name = input('Please enter your first and last name: ')
    scores = askForScore()
    avg_score = calc_average(scores)
    letter_grade = determine_grade(avg_score)
    print(letter_grade)

def askForScore():
    score1 = float(input('Please enter the first test score:'))
    score2 = float(input('Please enter the second test score:'))
    score3 = float(input('Please enter the third test score:'))
    score4 = float(input('Please enter the fourth test score:'))
    score5 = float(input('Please enter the fifth test score:'))
    return (score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)



def calc_average(scores):
    avg_score = (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2] + scores[3] + scores[4]) / 5
    return avg_score



def determine_grade(avg_score):
   if avg_score >= 90 and avg_score <= 100:
       return 'A'
   elif avg_score >= 80 and avg_score <= 89:
       return 'B'
   elif avg_score >= 70 and avg_score <= 79:
       return 'C'
   elif avg_score >= 60 and avg_score <= 69:
       return 'D'
   else:
       return 'F'

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and tweaking! Now that I am looking at it, it makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: One last question regarding this one. For calc average you assigned scores[0] -scores[4] to the variable avg_score. Was this done based on the position of each score with score 1 being 0?

Comment: Correct, "scores" is an array, and array indexes start at 0.  You could shorten that line to "avg_score = sum(scores) / len(scores)" and it would work for arrays of different lengths.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the helpful tips and comments!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand some Python concepts such as the scope of variables, return statements and function arguments. In your case, for instance, `score1` ... `score5` inside `askForScore` are not "readable" by `calc_average`. In fact, `calc_average` returns the values you need and those values need to be passed to the next function as arguments like this:

```
...
score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 = askForScore()
calc_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
...
```